# Non-deterministic output to console from stream() operation

Tags: kotlin, stream

I have strange result from my simple code:

```
val custom_list = listOf(CUSTOM_TAG+"first", CUSTOM_TAG+"second", CUSTOM_TAG+"third")
fun randomScore(){
    val myStream = custom_list.stream()
    myStream.filter { e ->
        println(CUSTOM_TAG+"text")
        e.contains("third")
    }.forEach { e -> println(e) }
}
```

Somethimes I get:

```
1000_text
1000_text
1000_third
```

and another time I get

```
1000_text
1000_text
1000_text
1000_third
```

Could someone can explain why I get random result and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

This code will **always** print same result (for `CUSTOM_TAG = "1000"`), and it is:

```
1000text
1000text
1000text
1000third
```

First three lines of `1000text` are printed in `filter` lambda (precisely from `println(CUSTOM_TAG+"text")`) After that step, on your console log you should see:

```
1000text
1000text
1000text
```

Moving forward, from all elements of initial `custom_list` only `CUSTOM_TAG+"third"` value passes this filter, which results in one element stream.

Finally, you call `forEach { e -> println(e) }` on it, and because it is one element stream, only one `1000third` is printed, which results in:

```
1000text
1000text
1000text
1000third
```

Comment: no, sometimes I got only 2x "1000text" :) And it is my problem